# Java OpenCV использование метода VideoCapture()

Tags: java, opencv

уточните как получить кадр с WEB камеры в OpenCV

```
public class HelowTest {

     public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("Welcome to OpenCV " + Core.VERSION);
            System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

            VideoCapture ip_cam = new VideoCapture();

            ip_cam.open(0);//  1. передача в метод камеры по умолчанию
            // ip_cam.open("http://......") 2.вот так кадр с WEB камеры, судя по мануалу, но это не работает.

            if (!ip_cam.isOpened())
            {
                System.out.print("Error while trying to open the webcam");
                return;
            }

            System.out.println("Success!");

            ip_cam.release();
        }

}
```

Comment: c Ip камеры, так будет верно)

Comment: ip_cam.open("http://......") должно работать при условии, что OpenCV скомпилирован с поддержкой ffmpeg